# WordPress - Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes)

Tags: php, wordpress

I keep getting this error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes). This appeared when I was activating the new plugins necessary for a new theme in my WordPress website. I added the following code to my `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M' );
```

However, after adding this code and doing a hard refresh in my WordPress administrative area the error message has not gone away. How can I fix this?

Comment: There are a few different values to change memory limits. Try all three mentioned here: https://www.themepunch.com/faq/how-to-increase-your-wordpress-memory/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress' `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` only restricts the memory usage for the wordpress application. It doesn't increase the memory limit for php. So you still need to increase php's memory limit. You can do this in the php.ini or if you don't have access then add this to your wp-config

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```